# Does the cavity magnetron in a microwave oven produce x-rays?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, x-rays, microwaves

It seems like it should due to bremsstrahlung, since we're talking about electrons with 5-7KeV of energy slamming into the walls of the device, but I've found no information about this online, so I'm assuming something else must be happening. CRT-style TVs and computer monitors both have this problem, so my guess is that most of the energy is being bled out of the electrons to form microwaves. Am I right?

Also, what happens to the production of microwaves as the magnets on the magnetron slowly lose strength?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a google search for "magnetron x-rays" yields quite a bit of information. From this [data sheet](http://www.alphatrononline.com/images/pdfs/MG6028.pdf):

> High voltage magnetrons emit a significant intensity of X-rays
>   not only from the cathode sidearm but also from the output
>   waveguide. These rays can constitute a health hazard unless
>   adequate shielding for X-ray radiation is provided. This is a
>   characteristic of all magnetrons and the X-rays emitted
>   correspond to a voltage much higher than that of the anode.

A quick [further glance](http://books.google.ca/books?id=sTodOiFYJmEC&lpg=PA362&ots=YRPTdJ0LAZ&dq=kev%20x-ray%20penetration%20depth&pg=PA362#v=onepage&q=kev%20x-ray%20penetration%20depth&f=false) seems to show that the penetration depth for x-rays into most materials at 7keV is [dismal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAttenuation.svg).

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified in my post that I was strictly interested in lower power ones you might find in your home - the datasheet you linked to is for a 1MW magnetron. I guess we can assume some x-rays, but very few are created and most are absorbed (although the data for attenuation depth seems like it should be a lot longer based on some of the things I've read. Most of this is new to me, so I've probably made a mistake somewhere...)

Comment: [This](http://web-docs.gsi.de/~stoe_exp/web_programs/x_ray_absorption/index.php) is what's throwing me off. It seems to be saying that iron does almost nothing for low energies, but that's directly at odds with your link and a corroborating page I found. Am I completely misreading this one?

Comment: What are you using as your energy and target length? 5 KeV and 1mm gives zero transmission for Fe.

Comment: Hah! I think I was ignoring the units on it and typed in 5000 KeV instead of 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NASA Armstrong avionics tech here - RF specialist.  The old medical studies on RF state a safe voltage level would be below 5,000 volts for the transmitter.  Above that, the possibility of parasitic X-rays increases with voltage, especially in radar equipment.  From what I understand so far, microwave oven magnetrons typically need about 4,000 volts from their transformer to oscillate, so it is within the safe range.